# Login Logout in Navbar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, logging

I hope you are ok.

I'm trying to switch to log out in Navabar when the user is logged in, but when I console log I get isloggedin false, even though the user is logged in and the token is stored in localstorage.

here is my code:

App.js

```js
const App = () => {
    const [isLoggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false)
    console.log(isLoggedIn)
  
    const handleLogin = token => {
      if (!token) return
      localStorage.setItem('token', token)
  
      setLoggedIn(true)
    }
  
    const handleLogout = () => () => {
      setLoggedIn(false)
      localStorage.clear()
    }
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Navbar isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} logout={handleLogout} />
        <Switch>
          <Route 
            exact path='/'
            component={props => (
              <Login {...props} onLogin={handleLogin} />
            )}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/signin" component={Signin}></Route> 
          <Route exact path="/feed" component={Feed}></Route> 
          <Route exact path="/withuser" component={Withuser}></Route>      
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  ) 
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Navbar.js:

```js
const TheNavbar = (props) => {
    console.log(props)
    return (
        <div className="navbar">
            <Navbar>
                <NavbarBrand>
                    <NavLink id="logo" tag={Link} exact to="/">
                        <img src="/img/logounax.png" alt="image" style={{ width: 150 }} />
                    </NavLink> 
                </NavbarBrand>
                <Nav>
                  {props.isLoggedIn ? (
                    <Nav>
                        <NavLink className="link-pink" tag={Link} exact to="/feed">
                        Profile
                        </NavLink>
                        <NavLink
                        className="link-pink"
                        tag={Link}
                        exact to="/"
                        onClick={props.logout()}>
                        Logout
                        </NavLink>
                    </Nav>
                  ) : (
                    <Nav>
                        <NavLink className="link-pink" tag={Link} exact to="/">
                        Login
                        </NavLink> 
                        <NavLink className="link-pink" tag={Link} exact to="/signin">
                        Signin
                        </NavLink>
                    </Nav>
                  )}   
                </Nav>
            </Navbar>
        </div>
    )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Any ideas why is this happening?

Thank you in advance.

(Post edited)

Comment: It looks like ok to me . You might have to use `useEffect` if state is not updating correctly. Better would be can you add your code [here](http://react.new/). Currently your code is not giving exact clarity

Comment: @ShubhamVerma thank you for your answer, I have added the code, let me know if it is ok for your or if you need more details....

Comment: currently code is not completed. Can you add complete code?

Comment: Is it ok now? @ShubhamVerma

Comment: I dont see any new changes. What I mean update complete code. For example your `App` component is not complete. Can you add complete file?

Comment: Ok, I have edited the post. But in codesandbox, I have added all the components that are affected by this issue.

Comment: Where is sandbox url. I can't see that link. It will help in debugging more easily

Comment: Thanks @ShubhamVerma here is the link: https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-bush-to8bf?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  check your code there are some issue. You are trying toke check on `handleLogin`  which will only check when you click on `handleLogin`. What happen if user refresh the page. It will ideally redirect to dashboard page if token is available. So you have to add `useEffect` which checks on component mount. Basically you need to add this in your `App.js` component. It will check when component is mounted first time only and if token is available it will set it

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("token")) {
      setLoggedIn(true);
    }
  }, []);
```

Just add this snippet in your file. It automatically works if every other things are correct.

You still dont added complete code ;-). But I dont think it will required. This will solve your that problem

I modify your sandbox. If you want to test the functionality type `test` for both field. Here is the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-meitner-soh27?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thank you @Shubham, but it only works when I refresh the page, even in sandbox. I'm going to read about it online to try to find the solution, but if you have any idea it will be welcome. Thanks for your help! ;)

Comment: @Guerreri88 Its happening because you haven't called `onLogin` inside your `Login` component. I have updated sandbox. Check again!

Comment: fantastic!! it worked! I really appreciate it! Thanks.

Comment: Great. Good luck!